# Is there any auto-completion for R in jupyterlab?

Tags: r, jupyter-lab

Kite can only auto complete python code in jupyterlab.

Is there a similar plug-in that allows R code to be automatically completed？

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `jupyterlab-lsp` offers auto-completion (along other IDE features). It uses Language Server Protocol which requires you to install both:

- one or more language servers (for R use [R language server](https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver)), and
- an extension to JupyterLab ([jupyterlab-lsp](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp)).

and then to enable `continuousHinting` option in Code Completion settings (via Advanced Settings Editor).

If you use JupyterLab 3.0 installed via `conda` it is as simple as:

```
conda install -c conda-forge 'jupyterlab>=3.0.0,<4.0.0a0' jupyterlab-lsp jupyter-lsp-r
```

If you use JupyterLab 3.0 installed via pip instead:

```
pip install 'jupyterlab>=3.0.0,<4.0.0a0' jupyterlab-lsp
R -e 'install.packages("languageserver")'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!This is very practical for me

Comment: Does this work for Rscript open as notebook?

Comment: Yes, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

install nbextentations for jupyterlab.
nbextentations already have lightweigt auto complete add-on.lightweigth but enough for me.

link: https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: This is for jupyter notebook, not jupyterlab.