# VS Code IntelliSense inside R magic

Tags: python, r, visual-studio-code

Suppose that one is using an `ipyn` notebook, with `R` magic cells. Can `IntelliSense` work for the `R` code inside the R magic cells?

I have extensively searched the web but found nothing so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can install NB package for jupyter-notebook: [Is there any auto-completion for R in jupyterlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65729307/is-there-any-auto-completion-for-r-in-jupyterlab)

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

Comment: Thanks, @MingJie-MSFT, for your answer. I have tried it and, unfortunately, no autocompletion is offered to user. Please, notice that the `ipynb` file has cells in Python and cells in R (through R magic).